# Julia dataframe where a column is an array of arrays?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'm trying to create a table where each row has time-series data associated with a particular test-case.

```
julia> df = DataFrame(var1 = Int64[], var2 = Int64[], ts = Array{Array{Int64, 1}, 1})
0x3 DataFrames.DataFrame
```

I'm able to create the data frame. Each `var1`, `var2` pair is intended to have an associated time series.

I want to generate data in a loop and want to append to this dataframe using `push!`

I've tried

```
julia> push!(df, [1, 2, [3,4,5]])
ERROR: ArgumentError: Length of iterable does not match DataFrame column count.
  in push! at /Users/stro/.julia/v0.4/DataFrames/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:871
```

and

```
julia> push!(df, (1, 2, [3,4,5]))
ERROR: ArgumentError: Error adding [3,4,5] to column :ts. Possible type mis-match.
 in push! at /Users/stro/.julia/v0.4/DataFrames/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:883
```

What's the best way to go about this? Is my intended approach even the right path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've accidentally put the type of a vector in instead of an actual vector. This declaration will work:

```
df = DataFrame(var1 = Int64[], var2 = Int64[], ts = Array{Int64, 1}[])
```

Note the change from `Array{Array{Int64, 1}, 1}`, which is a type, to `Array{Int64, 1}[]`, which is an actual vector with that type.

Then things work:

```
julia> push!(df, (1, 2, [3,4,5]))

julia> df
1x3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ var1 │ var2 │ ts      │
┝━━━━━┿━━━━━━┿━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━┥
│ 1   │ 1    │ 2    │ [3,4,5] │
```

Note that your other example, using `[1, 2, [3,4,5]]` still does not work. This is because a quirk in Julia's array syntax means that the comma `,` operator does concatenation, so in fact `[1, 2, [3,4,5]]` means `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. This behaviour is weird and will be fixed in Julia 0.5, but is preserved in 0.4 for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Fengyang.  That seems obvious now that I see it :) Also, thank you for clarifying the `,` behavior.  If I understand correctly, `(1, 2, [3,4,5])` creates a tuple literal with these values.  The *intent* of `[1, 2, [3,4,5]]` was to create a array, with `x[1] = 1, x[2] = 2, x[3] = [3,4,5]`, but does not due to the concatenation behavior of `,`.