# Julia DataFrames: create new column of arrays based on other columns

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'm working with a dataset that I read in from a csv. I have columns p1, p2, p3, and p4 that I would like to combine into a single column whose values are the array [p1 p2 p3 p4].

```
x = DataFrame(randn(100,4))
names!(x, [:p1; :p2; :p3; :p4])

x[:test] = x[[:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4]]
x # Doesn't work
```

The result of the code above has a 100x4 DataFrames.DataFrame in every row of the data.

I saw this question [Julia dataframe where a column is an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729891/julia-dataframe-where-a-column-is-an-array-of-arrays) but it doesn't address how to add a new array column as a function of the existing columns of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value assigned to a new column should be a Vector, but `x[[:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4]]` is a DataFrame, which will be repeated to *a Vector of DataFrames*.

I suggest you use Tuple rather than Vector to get better performance, it can be achieved by this code:

```
x[:test] = collect(zip(x[:p1],x[:p2],x[:p3],x[:p4]))
```

If you really need a Vector, this code can help:

```
x[:test] = map(collect, zip(x[:p1],x[:p2],x[:p3],x[:p4]))
```

(it looks a bit tricky. collect a Tuple returns a Vector)